# Google Form Script for Next Working Day Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I made a google form for request submissions. However some requestors tend to submit their forms after office hours and take the date they submitted it as the start date. That being said, if they submitted on a Friday night for example, there are 2 days of the weekend that should be accounted for and yet sometimes they would follow up and it will be communicated that they submitted it 3 or 4 days ago.

I would like to ask how can I make a Google Form script that will automatically set the date to the next working day, when the submitted form is beyond office hours (ends at 6PM)? So that it will reflect on the PDF form that is generated automatically (this one is already in place).

The timestamp will still be the original time of submission, so I would know when it was really submitted and that it was submitted beyond office hours. Looking forward to your insights!

Comment: Make a simple formula. If the today date is Friday then make it next Monday by adding 3 days.

Comment: You can solve this programmatically as well - check the time & day of the submitted and based on those, set it to the wanted one. Why isn't this an option to you?

Comment: hello @ale13, the reason is I don't know how to begin with it. My coding skills is very, very noob. I' more adept in excel than scripting. For the PDF auto-generation I was able to do the google script on sheets. But for the question posted above, I tried and looked online for parallel google scripts online to build it, but I can't put it together.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis, can you help me walk thru the code? Or share a link with a similar approach and I will figure it out from there? Thanks in advance.